# Automatically show connected mass storage devices on Windows desktop

Tags: windows, usb, desktop, usb-storage

Is there way to automatically display connected mass storage devices on the Windows desktop, like most Unix-based operating systems are doing?

I didn't find any native ways to do that, but maybe there are some third-party tools to add that feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [DeskDrive](http://mike-ward.net/deskdrive/)

> Desk Drive™ solves a really annoying problem. You pop a USB thumb drive or DVD into your computer and then you have to open Window's Explorer and find the mapped drive or folder. Desk Drive adds a desktop icon pointing to the drive automatically. Remove the media and the shortcut goes away. Brilliantly simple and effective.

[image]

### [Desktop Media](http://www.ianandmonica.com/desktopmedia/)

> Desktop Media is small application for Windows (any flavor) that automatically adds drive icons to your desktop. It will detect USB drives, fixed drives (ie. your hard drives), CD/DVD drives, network drives, and even RAM disk drives. For removable media (such as USB drives and CD/DVD drives), it will only add the drive to your desktop if it is present. So if you have a CD/DVD drive, but no disc is present, you won't see the icon on your desktop.

[image]

Comment: Desktop media simply don't work for me, don't know why, maybe because it's outdated and don't work with windows seven. But Desk Drive does the job, thanks.

Comment: But DeskDrive is a little buggy when sometimes not allowing to unmount removable media :/

Comment: enter image description here